# How can you have an isometry without a metric/coordinates?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, isometry

I'm self-studying Artin's Algebra and I'm getting a bit thrown through a loop on isometries (in Chapter 6, in case you're curious). Specifically, a section about change of coordinates:

> Let $P$ denote an $n$-dimensional space. The formula $t_a\phi$ for an isometry depends on our choice of coordinates [...]. To analyze the effect of such a change, we begin with an isometry $f$, a point $p$ of $P$, and its image $q=f(p)$, without reference to coordinates. When we introduce our coordinates, the space $P$ becomes identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the points $p$ and $q$ have coordinates say [...].

I don't understand how we can have an isometry $f$ before we've chosen coordinates and identified the space with $\mathbb{R}^n$, we don't even have a distance to preserve under $f$. I completely understand how the formula for an isometry changes if we have the formula for a set of coordinates and want to express it in another, but I don't get how we can have an isometry existing without respect to any coordinates as the quote mentions (in this case - I get that we could have something more general like a metric space, but Artin's not talking about that here).

Comment: Artin is thinking of $\Bbb R^n$ and its usual distance without specifying any underlying coordinates. We can talk about the distance between two points without reference to specific coordinates. (For example, in affine geometry, the vector from one point to another is defined, even though we have no specified origin.)

Comment: Perhaps Artin's use of the indefinite article "an", in the phrase *an $n$-dimensional space* is important here. I would not be so sure that Artin is talking about *the* $n$-dimensional space $\mathbb R^n$. Perhaps he is talking about *an* $n$-dimensional space such as the kernel of the linear function $T(x,y,z) = x+y+z$, which is a good example of a 2-dimensional space with a metric.